# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eel'

Tags: python, html, eel

I got a problem while importing 'eel', I reinstalled Python and updated it to newest version, and did 'pip install eel' but still nothing works for me, it just says:

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eel'
```

[image]

I am installing it on command prompt.

Comment: Yeah, command prompt.

Comment: Are you sure you installed `python` correctly? Maybe you missed something? You can check this question out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: Yeah I just checked it, still doesn't work. I tried everything, even installing it from PyCharm packages. It just doesn't find it. Probably I'm just going to use TKinter.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: are you in a virtual environment?

Comment: Nah, I'm doing it on my pc.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
python -m pip install eel
```

Comment: Just tried it. Still doesn't work. When I type "import eel" in PyCharm it already without any run shows that there isn't a package named "eel", but when I try "pip show eel" it shows it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
pip3 install eel
```

This works for me.

Comment: I found a solution, so basically I tried everything, but nothing did work, then I just tried installing modules from "Python Project" setting in PyCharm and only that worked.